# Two cell in a row,UITableview

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I want to have a two cell in a row,as in contacts we have “Text message” and “Add to favourites” in a single row how to do that….
Is that Splitting a cell into two?

can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

For that you're going to have to create your own custom cell which contains two cells. Perhaps the easiest way to do that would be to create a cell which contains two buttons. It's somewhat a hack, but it's the easiest way.

If you go with that route, you won't even have to subclass, you can simply prepare your content view with the two buttons, and set that as the cell's content.

Comment: I'll leave that up as an exercise for you to figure out. It's the best to learn. ;)